# Touchscreen PC settings in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, touchscreen

I installed the exact same Windows 7 on two identical touch PCs.
The problem is that if I want to activate something by a button on one PC I just need to click and on the other I need to swipe.

I compared all the touchscreen settings but could not find anything. Does anyone have suggestions?